# sql eliminate dupliates with Max Date

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
(
 Select Event.EventID, Event_Reps.LastName , Event_reps.FirstName, Cost.EventDate
 From Cost WITH(NOLOCK) 
 inner join Event WITH(NOLOCK) on Cost.EventID = Event.EventID 
 inner join Event_Reps WITH(NOLOCK) on Cost.EventRep = Event_Reps.EventRep 
 where Event.EventID = 66
 and Event_Reps.Division = 'Houston' and Cost.CostAmt = 0 
 ) as table1
```

As there are duplicate records in the Cost table for a given EventID,  I need to find the one that has the greatest EventDate.
I am not sure how to change the above query such that it does what it does but eliminates the duplicates and give me the Cost record that has the max EventDate.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways to skin a cat... Test each one out to find out which performs better with your table design and RDBMS. I'm fairly sure I've missed some ways out too.

**WINDOWED FUNCTIONS**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  Event.EventID, 
                    Event_Reps.LastName , 
                    Event_reps.FirstName, 
                    Cost.EventDate, 
                    MAX(Cost.EventDate) OVER(PARTITION BY EventID) [MaxEventDate]
            FROM    Cost WITH(NOLOCK) 
                    INNER JOIN Event WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        ON Cost.EventID = Event.EventID 
                    INNER JOIN Event_Reps WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        ON Cost.EventRep = Event_Reps.EventRep 
            WHERE   Event.EventID = 66
            AND     Event_Reps.Division = 'Houston' 
            AND     Cost.CostAmt = 0 
        ) as table1
WHERE   MaxEventDate = EventDate
```

**OR**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  Event.EventID, 
                    Event_Reps.LastName , 
                    Event_reps.FirstName, 
                    Cost.EventDate,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EventID ORDER BY Cost.EventID) [RowNumber]
            FROM    Cost WITH(NOLOCK) 
                    INNER JOIN Event WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        ON Cost.EventID = Event.EventID 
                    INNER JOIN Event_Reps WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        ON Cost.EventRep = Event_Reps.EventRep 
            WHERE   Event.EventID = 66
            AND     Event_Reps.Division = 'Houston' 
            AND     Cost.CostAmt = 0 
        ) as table1
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
```

**OR AGGREGATES**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  Event.EventID, 
                    Event_Reps.LastName , 
                    Event_reps.FirstName, 
                    Cost.EventDate,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EventID ORDER BY Cost.EventID) [RowNumber]
            FROM    Cost WITH(NOLOCK) 
                    INNER JOIN Event WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        ON Cost.EventID = Event.EventID 
                    INNER JOIN Event_Reps WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        ON Cost.EventRep = Event_Reps.EventRep 
                    INNER JOIN
                    (   SELECT  EventID, MAX(EventDate) [EventDate]
                        FROM    Cost
                        GROUP BY EventID
                    ) MaxCost
                        ON MaxCost.EventID = Cost.EventID
                        AND MaxCost.EventDate = Cost.EventDate
            WHERE   Event.EventID = 66
            AND     Event_Reps.Division = 'Houston' 
            AND     Cost.CostAmt = 0 
        ) as table1
```

**OR JOINS**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  Event.EventID, 
                    Event_Reps.LastName , 
                    Event_reps.FirstName, 
                    Cost.EventDate,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EventID ORDER BY Cost.EventID) [RowNumber]
            FROM    Cost WITH(NOLOCK) 
                    INNER JOIN Event WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        ON Cost.EventID = Event.EventID 
                    INNER JOIN Event_Reps WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        ON Cost.EventRep = Event_Reps.EventRep 
                    LEFT JOIN Cost c2
                        ON c2.EventID = Cost.EventID
                        AND c2.EventDate > Cost.EventDate
            WHERE   Event.EventID = 66
            AND     Event_Reps.Division = 'Houston' 
            AND     Cost.CostAmt = 0 
            AND     Cost.EventID IS NULL
        ) as table1
```

**OR EXISTS**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  Event.EventID, 
                    Event_Reps.LastName , 
                    Event_reps.FirstName, 
                    Cost.EventDate,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EventID ORDER BY Cost.EventID) [RowNumber]
            FROM    Cost WITH(NOLOCK) 
                    INNER JOIN Event WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        ON Cost.EventID = Event.EventID 
                    INNER JOIN Event_Reps WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        ON Cost.EventRep = Event_Reps.EventRep 
            WHERE   Event.EventID = 66
            AND     Event_Reps.Division = 'Houston' 
            AND     Cost.CostAmt = 0 
            AND     NOT EXISTS
                    (   SELECT  1
                        FROM    Cost c2
                        WHERE   c2.EventID = Cost.EventID
                        AND     c2.EventDate > Cost.EventDate
                    )
        ) as table1
```